# how to fix seams in quartz countertops

Tags: quartz

I have nasty seams in my quartz countertops after buying my first home a few years ago. How would I repair this? Here is a photo of the problem

[image]

Comment: If there are no tighteners under the counter to bring the edges closer, then about the only thing is to use some caulking to seal the gaps.

Comment: As I understand it, due to the way that the makers of countertop systems limit their product sales for things like the proper matching epoxy to get an effectively seamless finish, you have to hire a person with the correct dealer relationship to the maker of the countertop material to get those, who is also competent in using them. DIY approaches are likely to look like DIY approaches, here.

Comment: Try calling a company that specializes in countertops.  Here in Fla they are everywhere. Any good countertop company will have the epoxy to fill in a bad joint like you have.   The issue is most companies are too busy to send out techs to do repairs.  It may be different where you are.

Comment: well I am in northern California area so not sure if worth paying to repair it or wait and replace it with new countertops with a remodel in the future.

Comment: scrape all the crap out of the joint.  bleach the joint.  you get the countertop suction cup machine that can tension up the two pieces to minimize the gap.  get your epoxy and quartz dust and make up the filler.  apply the filler and scrap it flat.